# Split a column value into two columns in query output (DB2)

Tags: db2

How can I split a column value into two values in the output? I need have the numerals in one column and the alphabet in the other.

For Example **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja5jD.jpg)**

```
Existing
Column 
========
678J
2345K
```

I need the output to be:

```
Column 1            Column 2
========            ========
678                   J
2345                  K
```

The existing column can have 4 or 5 characters, as shown in the example. There is no space.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Both links point to the same image. Can you please check?

Comment: Which type of DB2 server are you using?  (ie which OS is DB2 running under?)  And which version?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert all letters to spaces & strip them away, then do the opposite with digits in the other column:

```
SELECT trim(translate(mycol,repeat(' ',26),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')) as col1,
       trim(translate(mycol,repeat(' ',10),'0123456789')) as col2
  FROM mytable
```

Adjust as necessary to translate additional characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the performance of WarrenT's solution, but it looks like very heavy solution. It does what it is supposed to be doing with little constraints on the the data. If you know more about the data, you can optimize.

*String always ends with 1 and only one letter*

```
select left(mycol, length(mycol)-1), right(mycol,1) from mytable
```